# Python Peewee SqliteQueueDatabase table does not get created

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I'm developing a multi-threaded application with SQLite database. I've done some research and it seems that SqliteQueueDatabase can deliver the required concurrency handling. I've dig through the documentation but it seems I haven't managed to see the whole picture how to start & initiate the database.

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.sqliteq import SqliteQueueDatabase

db = SqliteQueueDatabase(':memory:')


class Prime(Model):
    num = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        database = db


db.start()
db.connect()
db.create_tables([Prime])
print db.get_tables()  # prints []
db.stop()
```

After starting the database in the above example, I try to create the table for my model but it does not get created. What do I miss? I tried to find a peewee &  SqliteQueueDatabase example that covers the whole lifecycle but was unable to.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this problem and it seems that the read query completes before `create_tables()` does.

My fix is to throw in back-to-back `db.stop()` `db.start()` calls. Forcing code execution to wait until all database write queries are completed.

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.sqliteq import SqliteQueueDatabase

db = SqliteQueueDatabase('db.sqlite3')


class Prime(Model):
    num = IntegerField()

class Meta:
    database = db


db.start()
db.connect()
db.create_tables([Prime])
db.stop() #  Wait for create_tables() to complete
db.start() #  Continue execution
print db.get_tables()
db.stop()
```

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated to the original issue, but this can definitely happen due to how python schedules threads. Another option is to insert a small time.sleep() after your call to db.create_tables() to get python to switch contexts.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an in-memory database. In-memory databases use a connection-per-thread. So unless you specifically use the shared-memory mode (you'll have to consult the sqlite docs) you are out-of-luck.

Use a file-based db and your example will run fine.

Comment: I'm writing a multithreaded application and I want to make it configurable from a file whether the application uses in-memory or file db. I've read that to achieve this in-memory connection needs to be shared amongst threads. I've also read that sqlite supports this (serialized mode) but the python sqlite driver doesn't. That's why I choose SqliteQueueDatabase (and peewee). Am I on an impossible mission here?

I've tried what you recommended and modified ':memory:' to a filename, still doesn't create the table. If I use SqliteDatabase and remove db.start & db. stop, it creates the table.

Comment: You're on a fool's errand homie.

Comment: Charles Could you please help me why doesn't the example code work for file databases neither?

Comment: The equivalent code works for me using an ordinary file database.

Comment: Note that SqliteQueueDatabase is tested, and I have been using it on a project that's been deployed for well over a year without issues.

Comment: Could the problem be that I'm using Python 2.7?

Comment: peewee is tested using a matrix of python versions and database backends. 2.7 is included.

Comment: this should work:

`db = SqliteQueueDatabase('file::memory:?cache=shared', uri=True)`

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is that I haven't used peewee, SqliteQueueDatabase or any ORM but sqlite3 and threading.

Using a sort of singleton trick I had basically 1 instance of an object that had a connection property, therefore a single connection instance was shared with all the threads. I had to set `check_same_thread=False` when connecting to sqlite otherwise different threads can't share the same connection.

Below is a simplified version:

```
import sqlite3
import threading

class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Dao(object, metaclass=Singleton):

    def __init__(self, conf=None):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(
                conf.db,
                check_same_thread=False
            )
```

The first time I've instantiated the `Dao` class in the main thread and passed a configuration to `__init__`. Later whichever thread needed to use the database, it just created a `Dao` object. However due to the Singleton trick the caller just got a reference to the already existing instance that also included the already established connection.

I added all my DB operations as methods to this `Dao` class. In order to avoid repeating the locking, I've created decorators using `wraps`.

```
from functools import wraps

def transaction_read_write(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.lock.acquire()
        # execute wrapped method and perform commit
        try:
            ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.conn.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            # perform rollback in case of an error
            # also in real world application do some logging here
            self.conn.rollback()
            raise e
        finally:
            # release acquired lock
            self.lock.release()
        return ret
    return wrapper
```

I had a similar wrapper for read-only operations but without commit/rollback. I made it configurable in that one whether to perform locking during read-only operations -- just to be able to adjust locking behaviour without a new release should a DB concurrency issue occur in prod.

Now all I had to do is to add my custom transaction decorators to the `Dao` methods. (In real life a transaction can be made up from several SQL commands of course. Therefore I had some atomic methods without transaction annotation which were never called directly from outside. They were called only by some other `Dao` methods which performed several calls within a single transaction so these complex methods had transaction annotations. I was very careful with how large and how fast these transactions were because in my case the locking mechanism basically prevented the other threads from working with the DB at the same time.)

So a `Dao` method could look something like:

```
@transaction_read_write
def set_processed_files(self, id, num_files):
    cur = self.conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE jobs SET num_files = ? WHERE job_id = ?", (num_files, id))
```

At the end I decided not to use peewee but I hope there is something useful in my example.